# SQL innerjoin 3 tables with different PRIMARY keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join 3 tables together using the following sql command:

```
SELECT 
    tg.Kickoff,
    tg.League,
    tg.home,
    tg.away,
    ln.Full,
    ln.Mysite,
    ln.Country,
    tl.mydb
  FROM `todaysgames` AS tg
 INNER JOIN `leaguenames` AS ln ON tg.League = ln.Othersites
 INNER JOIN `teamlookup` AS tl ON tg.home = tl.websitedb
                                OR tg.away = tl.websitedb;
```

The issue is I get is it doubles each row.

What I am looking to do is for each tg.home and tg.away is replace it with the tl.websitedb (this basically amends the name).

would this be possible? (Below is the current output)

[image]

here is desired output[image]

Comment: Talking about primary keys, what *are* the tables' primary keys? Is `Othersites` a unique key for `leaguenames`? Is `websitedb` a unique key for `teamlookup`?

Comment: That's correct Thorsten - I have updated with images of the table to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I interprete your question correctly, you get two records per game where you only want one? This is because you join with teamlookup on tow conditions, thus finding two records per game.

Example:

*todaysgames*

```
Game  Home  Away
1     A     B
```

*teamlookup*

```
websitedb  mydb
A          DBA
B          DBB
```

*result*

```
Game  Home  Away  mydb
1     A     B     DBA
1     A     B     DBB
```

I guess you really want to get this instead:

```
Game  Home  Away  mydbHome  mydbAway
1     A     B     DBA       DBB
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
  tg.Kickoff,
  tg.League,
  tg.home,
  tg.away,
  ln.Full,
  ln.Mysite,
  ln.Country,
  tlh.mydb as mydb_home,
  tla.mydb as mydb_away
FROM todaysgames tg
JOIN leaguenames ln ON tg.League = ln.Othersites
JOIN teamlookup tlh ON tg.home = tlh.websitedb
JOIN teamlookup tla ON tg.away = tla.websitedb;
```

Comment: @sagi: Because there is no record in the table where websitedb equals *both* `home` *and* `away` (except for records where `home` = `away` which wouldn't make much sense).

Comment: Perfect - first time doing joins. Thank-you for you help and explanation